# How do I wipe a Sun Santricity SAN Array

Tags: security, storage-area-network, sun, secure-delete

I need to wipe all data from an out of support SUN Santricity array before we send it to EMC for a trade in.

(Yes EMC is took our SUN in part for a CX-480)

Does anyone have advice on how to wipe this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure those boxes don't have any 'self-erase' capability so you'd have to carve up all the storage into presentable LUNs, present them to one or most hosts, then use host-based erase tools to do a single-pass zero-wipe, then unpresent everything and delete the LUNs - it's the only way to be sure, without nuking from orbit obviously.